# Carry on luggage larger than rules for one leg

Tags: air-travel, luggage, united-airlines

I am flying United to Boston, and the dimensions of my carry-on baggage is 9x14x24 inches. The maximally allowed dimensions for United flights are however only 9x14x22 inches. Will I have to check it, or do I have 2 inches of wiggle room for the wheels?

Going home, I will fly Virgin American, which allow carry-ons of 9x14x25 inches, so I will be fine.

Comment: Flying to Boston from where on what aircraft?  2 inches is not a huge hassel on a newer wide body, but could be an issue on an older single aisle aircraft or commuter jet.

Comment: @Tom -- not to disagree with your principle that questions should contain enough information, clearly stated, to be answered, but in this case, it is unlikely that any route popular enough to be served by both United and Virgin American would also be unpopular enough to be serviced with commuter aircraft.  This isn't going to be Islip-Worchester.

Comment: @Malvolio - Virgin America uses small single aisle aircraft, the A320, so it is entirely conceivable that United Connection could fly the same route with 70 or 90 passenger commuter jets.  There are numerous routes in the US into major airports where the competing airlines vary between commuter and single aisle jets, some routes that even a single carrier will serve the route with both type aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the major airlines are pretty reasonable when it comes to carry-ons.  If you are not trying to drag a steamer trunk into the cabin, they will usually let you slide, and if they do have to stop you, they will usually check your bag on a courtesy basis and not charge you.

This is *not* true of Spirit and some of the European budget airlines, who are looking for a reason to jack you up.